# Programmatically set header length for pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading in data files using pandas. The data files have a header of varying length - 4 columns of ~50 rows, then the main data which is ~20 columns of 1000's of rows.

At the moment I have to manually specify the header=x, in the read_csv call but it would be great if I could somehow programmatically determine what the header needs to be within python.

Tried googling, and reading the documentation for read_csv, didn't come across much.

Comment: Please read [mre] and [edit] your question.

Comment: Why do you need to specify the header length in the first place?

Comment: Because when I load the file I want to access the dataset (from ~50 rows down) and the parameters used to create the data set (first ~50 rows). Between different versions of the program a different number of rows is used and it is annoying to change - the only solution I can think of is trying every row number up until 100 until there is no error (there is an error if the wrong header length is chosen).